# Создание светофора

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function change() {

    let duration = {
      red: 2000,
      yellow: 2000,
      green: 2000
    };

    let container = $(".main_block .active");

    setTimeout(function() {

      container.removeClass('active');

      let next = container.next();

      if (next.length == 0) {
        next = $(".main_block .red");
      }

      next.addClass('active');

      change();
    }, duration[container.data('color')]);
  }

  change();

})
```

```css
.main_block {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.red.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yellow.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.green.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_block">

  <div class="red active item" data-color="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow item" data-color="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green item" data-color="green"></div>

</div>
```

Как сделать так , после того , как потухнет зеленый возвращался в обратном порядке и так по кругу.

Comment: это бы на css надо делать =)

Comment: Возможно , но целью стоит реализовать это через js/jQuery=)

Comment: Что значит *возвращался в обратном порядке*?

Comment: сейчас он действует так : красный > желтый > зеленый и потом сразу перепрыгивает на красный. А мне нужно , чтобы потом он разворачивался так сказать , и шел обратно если можно так выразиться

Answer (score 1):

```js
let $tls = $(".traffic-light"),
  timeout = 200,
  light = [
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "#12d212"
  ];
  
function trafficLights (tls, idx, timeout, direction) {
    let tf = tls.eq(idx);    
    setTimeout (function() {
      tls.eq(idx - direction).removeAttr('style');
      tf.css('background-color', light[idx]);      
      if (idx == 2 || (idx == 0 && direction == -1)) {
        direction *= -1;
      }      
      idx += direction;
      trafficLights(tls, idx, timeout, direction);      
    }, timeout);
}

trafficLights($tls, 0, timeout, 1);
```

```css
.wrapper{background-color:#000;padding:5px;width:22px}
.traffic-light{width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid grey;border-radius:10px}
.traffic-light:nth-child(1){background-color:#350000}
.traffic-light:nth-child(2){background-color:#7b5702}
.traffic-light:nth-child(3){background-color:#1c3701}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="traffic-light"></div>
  <div class="traffic-light"></div>
  <div class="traffic-light"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: после зеленого перескакивает сразу на красный , это то я и хотел пофиксить

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  flag = true;
  let next;
  
  function change() {

    let container = $(".main_block .active");
    
    let duration = {
      red: 2000,
      yellow: 100,
      green: 2000,
    };
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      container.removeClass('active');
      next = flag ? container.next() : container.prev();
      next.addClass('active');
      flag = next.hasClass('green') ? false : next.hasClass('red') ? true : flag;
      console.log(next.attr('class'))
      change();
    }, duration[container.data('color')]);
  }
  change();

})
```

```css
.main_block {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.red.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yellow.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.green.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_block">

  <div class="red active item" data-color="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow item" data-color="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green item" data-color="green"></div>
</div>
```